# MarketingCloudSDK deviceId crash

Tags: ios

Hello I released an app with the marketingCloud-SDK 5.1.1 in it.
I can see crashes in crashlytics about the MarketingCloudSDK.

Do you know the problem and can you tell me in which situation this happens?

Here is the crashlog
[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: deviceid)

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException 0  CoreFoundation
>   0x183dd6d8c __exceptionPreprocess 1  libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x182f905ec objc_exception_throw 2  CoreFoundation
>   0x183d6f750 _CFArgv 3  CoreFoundation                 0x183ca4c6c
>   -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] 4  iphone-app                     0x10315a654 -[MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence
>   payloadForETAnalyticEntity:] (MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m:756) 5 
>   iphone-app                     0x1031572f4
>   __48-[MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence sendETAnalytics]_block_invoke_2 (MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m:464) 6  CoreFoundation
>   0x183db46c4 __NSArrayEnumerate 7  iphone-app
>   0x10315726c __48-[MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence
>   sendETAnalytics]_block_invoke.356
>   (MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m:469)

Comment: I haven't worked with Objective-C since before anonymous blocks were introduced, but it looks to me like this is an internal error within Marketing Cloud SDK unless `-[MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence sendETAnalytics]` is invoking a block your code passed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This crash occurs occasionally (timing dependent) when the user has done a "swipe to close", thus terminating your app. The timing issue is of the app going to the background just before that happens, the SDK processing analytics, and accessing a resource already released as part of the SDK's teardown.

Our next SDK release (scheduled for *very soon*) will have guards in place for this situation.